# generate random number with varying parameters using lapply in R

Tags: r, simulation, lapply

I need to generate random numbers (binomial) with varying parameters. 
I am trying to do that using `lapply` function.

This is my code so far:

```
lst1 <- list(n=c(10,20), size=c(100,200), q=c(0.1,0.2)) #list of variables

lapply(lst1, function(x) {
  rbinom(x[1],x[2],x[3])
})
```

Seems there is an error.

Then I tried this way as well,

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) {
  rbinom(x$n,x$size,x$q)
})
```

Still I am getting an error.
Can anyone help me to figure out the error ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better to use `Map` instead of `lapply` when the function needs to get a different set of parameters each time:

```
> Map(rbinom, lst1$n, lst1$size, lst1$q)
[[1]]
 [1] 15  7  8 12  9 11  4  9 12  7

[[2]]
 [1] 47 40 37 54 40 39 39 43 50 33 34 37 42 31 26 34 31 38 43 43
```

---

With `lapply` you could do it like this:

```
lapply(1:2, function(ind) rbinom(lst1$n[ind], lst1$size[ind], lst1$q[ind]))
[[1]]
 [1] 10 18  7  9  9 18  7  8  8 10

[[2]]
 [1] 46 42 44 37 38 40 52 44 42 38 40 35 41 46 44 38 41 32 61 33
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use `pmap` from `purrr` after making matching names of the `list` with the arguments of the function.

```
names(formals(rbinom))
#[1] "n"    "size" "prob"
```

Here the 'q' can be renamed as 'prob'

```
library(purrr)
names(lst1)[3] <- 'prob'
pmap(lst1, rbinom)
#[[1]]
# [1] 13  9 12 19 11  8 14 13 16  7

#[[2]]
# [1] 42 52 37 48 41 33 34 31 47 41 41 40 39 42 41 41 52 47 42 49
```